# How to improve the performance of SELECT queries with multiple JOINs on a 50GB database hosted on AWS m3.medium MySQL RDS?

Tags: mysql, optimization, join

Example query:

```
SELECT
    p.ListAgentEmail,
    p.ListAgentFirstName,
    p.ListAgentLastName,
    p.ListingKey

FROM
    Property_RES AS p

    INNER JOIN Property_RES_COUNTIES_OR_REGIONS
      ON Property_RES_COUNTIES_OR_REGIONS.ListingKey = p.ListingKey
    INNER JOIN Property_Lookup_COUNTIES_OR_REGIONS
      ON Property_RES_COUNTIES_OR_REGIONS.Value = Property_Lookup_COUNTIES_OR_REGIONS.Value
        AND Property_Lookup_COUNTIES_OR_REGIONS.LongValue IN ('Los Angeles','Orange','Riverside','San Diego','San Bernardino','Ventura')

    INNER JOIN Property_RES_LOCALE_LISTING_STATUSES
      ON Property_RES_LOCALE_LISTING_STATUSES.ListingKey = p.ListingKey
    INNER JOIN Property_Lookup_LOCALE_LISTING_STATUSES
      ON Property_RES_LOCALE_LISTING_STATUSES.Value = Property_Lookup_LOCALE_LISTING_STATUSES.Value
        AND Property_Lookup_LOCALE_LISTING_STATUSES.LongValue = 'Closed'

    INNER JOIN `Property_RES_PROPERTY_SUB_TYPE-RES`
      ON `Property_RES_PROPERTY_SUB_TYPE-RES`.ListingKey = p.ListingKey
    INNER JOIN `Property_Lookup_PROPERTY_SUB_TYPE-RES`
      ON `Property_RES_PROPERTY_SUB_TYPE-RES`.Value = `Property_Lookup_PROPERTY_SUB_TYPE-RES`.Value
        AND `Property_Lookup_PROPERTY_SUB_TYPE-RES`.LongValue = 'Single Family'

WHERE
    ListAgentEmail IS NOT NULL
```

EXPLAIN result:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: Property_Lookup_LOCALE_LISTING_STATUSES
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,LongValue
          key: LongValue
      key_len: 14
          ref: const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using index
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: Property_Lookup_PROPERTY_SUB_TYPE-RES
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,LongValue
          key: LongValue
      key_len: 25
          ref: const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using index
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: Property_Lookup_COUNTIES_OR_REGIONS
         type: range
possible_keys: PRIMARY,LongValue
          key: LongValue
      key_len: 24
          ref: NULL
         rows: 6
        Extra: Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: Property_RES_COUNTIES_OR_REGIONS
         type: ref
possible_keys: Value,ListingKey
          key: Value
      key_len: 8
          ref: mm_CARETS.Property_Lookup_COUNTIES_OR_REGIONS.Value
         rows: 32761
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 5. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: Property_RES_LOCALE_LISTING_STATUSES
         type: ref
possible_keys: Value,ListingKey
          key: ListingKey
      key_len: 16
          ref: mm_CARETS.Property_RES_COUNTIES_OR_REGIONS.ListingKey,mm_CARETS.Property_Lookup_LOCALE_LISTING_STATUSES.Value
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 6. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: p
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,ListAgentEmail
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: mm_CARETS.Property_RES_COUNTIES_OR_REGIONS.ListingKey
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 7. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: Property_RES_PROPERTY_SUB_TYPE-RES
         type: ref
possible_keys: Value,ListingKey
          key: ListingKey
      key_len: 16
          ref: mm_CARETS.Property_RES_COUNTIES_OR_REGIONS.ListingKey,mm_CARETS.Property_Lookup_PROPERTY_SUB_TYPE-RES.Value
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The table Property_RES is quite wide. It has 264 columns. Here are some specs:

```
+-------+--------+-------+------------+---------+
| rows  | data   | idx   | total_size | idxfrac |
+-------+--------+-------+------------+---------+
| 4.20M | 10.21G | 2.41G | 12.62G     |    0.24 |
+-------+--------+-------+------------+---------+
```

Indexes on Property_RES:

```
+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-----------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Non_unique | Key_name              | Seq_in_index | Column_name           | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-----------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
|          0 | PRIMARY               |            1 | ListingKey            | A         |     4201720 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
|          1 | BathsTotal            |            1 | BathsTotal            | A         |       30669 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
|          1 | BedroomsTotal         |            1 | BedroomsTotal         | A         |         124 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
|          1 | ClosePrice            |            1 | ClosePrice            | A         |      100040 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
|          1 | ListingDate           |            1 | ListingDate           | A         |       14438 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
|          1 | ListingID             |            1 | ListingID             | A         |     4201720 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
|          1 | ListPrice             |            1 | ListPrice             | A         |      525215 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
|          1 | ModificationTimestamp |            1 | ModificationTimestamp | A         |     4201720 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
|          1 | StreetName            |            1 | StreetName            | A         |      700286 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
|          1 | ZipCode               |            1 | ZipCode               | A         |        4422 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
|          1 | ListAgentEmail        |            1 | ListAgentEmail        | A         |      525215 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
|          1 | ClosingDate           |            1 | ClosingDate           | A         |       21437 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-----------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

All of the tables looking like *_Lookup_* have a schema similar to:

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `Property_Lookup_COUNTIES_OR_REGIONS` (
  `ShortValue` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LongValue` char(23) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Id` char(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Value` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Value`),
  KEY `LongValue` (`LongValue`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and all of the tables like *_RES_* have a schema like:

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `Property_RES_COUNTIES_OR_REGIONS` (
  `ListingKey` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Value` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY `Value` (`Value`),
  KEY `ListingKey` (`ListingKey`,`Value`),
  CONSTRAINT `Property_RES_COUNTIES_OR_REGIONS_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ListingKey`) REFERENCES `Property_RES` (`ListingKey`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `Property_RES_COUNTIES_OR_REGIONS_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Value`) REFERENCES `Property_Lookup_COUNTIES_OR_REGIONS` (`Value`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

As it stands, this and similar queries currently take approximately 10-45 minutes to execute. This is on an AWS RDS m3.medium server with 3.75GB of ram. Is this the best performance I can expect without changing the schema? Is there any database tuning or query optimizations I can make to improve performance?

Comment: I think that the IN subquery may be a problem. Have you tried to check the performance if you run 6 queries, with equality?

Comment: I haven't tried that, but I will and will report back. I currently am running a similar query, with an added `ClosingDate >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 180 DAY )` in the `WHERE` clause, and that has been running for hours.

Comment: Using char fields for querying is going to be slow. Can't you assign an ID to each possible values and search by ID?

Comment: @ypercube: I attempted running the same query, replacing IN (...) with = 'Los Angeles'. This query returned less than half the records and still took over 2.5 hours to complete.

Comment: @Alexandros: I ran the same query as @ypercube suggested, but then removed `LongValue = 'Los Angeles'` and replaced `Property_RES_COUNTIES_OR_REGIONS.Value = Property_Lookup_COUNTIES_OR_REGIONS.Value` with `Property_RES_COUNTIES_OR_REGIONS.Value = 32543252`,and did the same for all the other sub-joins. The query still took over 2 hours to run.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After testing the database with several different queries, I found that the query taking the longest was the simple SELECT base query on the Property_RES table. In order to return the ~60k records that fell within its criteria, it took over 2.5 hours.

In desperation, I recreated the database on a Linode 4096 VPS. It is already proving to be much much faster. For instance, a query which once took 5 hours 50 minutes took 8 min 50 seconds.

It seems to me that the low IOPS provided by unprovisioned RDS instances were the limiting factor in this case, causing slow data retrieval times when compared to the masses of CPU and RAM available (and going unused). Due to the prohibitive cost of provisioned IOPS, I have changed now completely to Linode.

Comment: You probably need some composite indexes as well. EAV designs need them for the queries to be efficient.

Comment: ...for the queries to be less inefficient ;-)

Comment: I question for the correctness  of your conclusion. You claim "masses of CPU and RAM available (and going unused)." - that is a sign of a massively bad configuration. At least the RAM would be used as cache when properly configured. Low CPU usage is typical for databases, but not using RAM means as cache when available is a beginner configuration error, not a problem of AWS IO.

Comment: @TomTom - The RAM was absolutely used as a cache - nearly all of it was allocated to MySQL. However, the RAM was unused in the sense that the vast majority of queries resulted in cache misses, which required the database to read the data from the hard disk instead.

Comment: @TomTom - Actually Percona Perfomance Blog just did an article relating to this: https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/06/01/use-provisioned-iops-volumes-for-aws/